# How does Instagram implement UIPreviewAction in iPhones which don't support 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

The latest update of Instagram offers a 3D Touch like experience for the user which can be mimicked via PeekPop library. But Instagram is a step ahead offering preview actions when an image is long pressed. How to achieve that? Thanks.